# I try to use for loop to keep DRY way of coding, but output confuses me [closure issue]

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is such DOM structure:

```
<div class="info" id="step1">
<a href="#" id="next_step_1"> ok </a>
</div>

<div class="info" id="step2">
<a href="#" id="next_step_2"> ok </a>
</div>

<div class="info" id="step3">
<a href="#" id="next_step_3"> ok </a>
</div>
```

... (so on)

Div    `.info` has `display:none` property (except 1), so what I want to achieve: when I click ok, this div fades out, next div fades in.

Of course, that's not DRY to write function to each div, so I tried this:

```
  for (var i=1; i<5; i++){
       $("body").delegate('#next_step_'+i, 'click', function(){
       $("#step"+i).fadeOut();
       $("#step"+i+1).fadeIn();
       });

    }
```

This code didn't work, and I tried:

```
  for (var i=1; i<5; i++){
       $("body").delegate('#next_step_'+i, 'click', function(){
       alert("#step"+i)
       });

    }
```

And alert worked(so on delegate `i` was 1) but alert was `#step5`.

That confuses me, I supposed JS output 5 functions for each div... Help me get this around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you just use the class `info`? It saves separately assigning a delegation functions

```
$("body").delegate(".info", 'click', function(){
    $(this).fadeOut();
    $(this).next().fadeIn();
});
/*
    As of jQuery 1.7+ 
    $("body").on("click", ".info", function(){
        $(this).fadeOut();
        $(this).next().fadeIn();
    });
*/
```

Also, as of jQuery 1.7+ you should be using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). `on` combines the `bind`, `live`, and `delegate` functions.

You code doesn't work because of an closure issue:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        $("body").delegate('#next_step_' + i, 'click', function () {
            alert("#step" + i)
        });
    })(i);
}
```

I can't really explain it. I just know I had an issue like this and I got it fixed using that ([**See**](http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/2UGfn/)). I still encourage using the first method.

Comment: Hmm... thank you for your response, I upvoted, but I'm intrested no as much in result itself, as in improving my understanding of how to code and why this doesn't work

Comment: yes, I notice the difference, but can't understand Js behaviour

Comment: @JoeHalfFace Check the other answer. It has a better description.

Answer (score 5):

delegate has been superseeded by `on` as of 1.7.0

Use `on` to delegate the events instead

Try this

```
$("body").on('click', '.info', function(){
    var $this = $(this);      
    $this.nextAll('.info').first().fadeIn();
    $this.fadeOut();
});
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Hy7n5/1/)**

You code does not work as because of **classic closure issue**. The value of `i` will be shared by all instances of events as , events happen at a later time. So `i` will always be the value of the last iteration.

**Your example**

I prefer this than binding it in IFFY

```
 for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        $("body").delegate('#next_step_' + i, 'click', bindClick(i));
    }

    function bindClick(i) {
        return function() {
            alert("#step"+i)
        }
    }
```

When you return a function , the function forms a closure , saving the state of the outermost variables at the time the function was bound creating a new scope that is unique to the function that is returned. As the variables are tied to the scope you can access the right values.

If you have a difficult time understanding the above method the same can be written as as IIFE( Immediately Invoked Function Expression), that is executing the function immediately that creates a new scope for the variables in which it is executed, which is what shawn has written.

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Hy7n5/)**

But in your case you are trying to access the variable that is common to all the handlers.

Comment: +1 Your explanation is better than mine (by far)